# Magento product page adjustments

Tags: php, magento, model, controller, product

I need to display on product page few fields from corresponding row of MANUFACTURERS table

I don't know how to find required Model and Controller for that task.

Manufacturers table is the table where manufacturers stored

And there is another one table Manufacturers_products (manufacturer_id, product_id)

What I did is added 2 checkboxes to backend  add/edit manufacturers form and added to fields for this checkboxes in manufacturers table.

Now I need to display 2 types of strings for each of fields, depending on user choice, during process of manufacturers create.

For example, if 1st checkbox is checked, then on all products, that have the same manufacturer, text row must appear, telling that 1st checkbox is checked. The same for the second.

Actually I need this checkboxes take part in product compare and filtering.

Any information will help. Thanks.

Comment: It will be great if you give us more info. From where this manufacturers table comes? Is it parts of some Magento extension for linking manufacturers to product? Can you the table schema? Help us and we will help you ;)

Comment: I'm not magento expert. Maybe it is part of extension, but I din't executed any sql queries to paste any table into DB. I've installed magento and copy/paste FME Manufacturers module files to Magento, as it was written in module installation pdf

Comment: Do you talk about this extension: http://www.fmeextensions.com/shop-by-manufacturers.html As I see it's commercial extension and I can't download it for free and to look at it. I suspect, that the extension has setup which have has created the table, that you mentioned. It will be great if you list the available models and their methods and also to tell us which fields you like to display.

Comment: This task is not to modify Extension. I already did all required modifications to extension. I changed add/edit manufacturer form (Zend Form) by adding two fields $form->addField('name','checkbox', $paramsArray). Now I need to display manufacturer checkbox status for the products with the same manufacturer.   It is about to change products, but not this extension.  

p.s. are you sure, that there is no manufacturers tables in default installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

1) Added new block to Manufacturers module layout ( **manufacturers.xml**), situated in the layout folder of frontend site theme

2) Created new block class in Manufacturers module Block folder and specified it in the **type** attribute of my block, added on the **1st step**

3) In the block class, you must extend protected method

`_tohtml()`

by adding your own behavior. Don't forget to call

`parent::_tohtml()`

4) To work with **Manufacturers** table, you must add new method to **Manufacturers** model of this module and make here a call to

```
$this->getRequest()->yourNewMethodName()
```

5) Add new method with the same name to the **Manufacturers** model, placed in **Mysql4** folder or **Model** folder in this module. Here you must add your query, that will retrieve data from manufacturers table

You can also create enable/disable config parameter. To do this, you must read about Magento **system.xml** configuration (**Tabs,Sections,Groups,Fields**)

This solution steps are acceptable for any magento module. Hope this helps to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the Model and controller of the extension then you need to check the Module files. In order to check that just

a) Go to app/code/community or app/code/local there you will find the Package name like FME and inside that folder you will find your module name.

b) In order to check the Model just Go inside the Module folder->etc folder and check the config.xml

c) In config.xml you will find a code like

```
  <entities>
          <modelname>
                <table>tablename</table>
          </modelname>
  </entities>
```

In the above code Modelname tag will give the modelname

d) In order to find the controller you need to check the controllers folder.

hope this helps!!